# Problem with sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

It tells me to try to run `apt-get -f install`.  The error says "Unmet dependencies. Try using -f."  When I try `sudo apt-get -f install` I get an error that says

```
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken Pipe)

Errors were encountered while processing
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic_3.16.--70.90~14.04.1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-67-generic_3.16.0-67.87~14.04.1_i.386.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands.  You might have to run them more than once to get all the updated repository links correct.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I've tried those  many many times and while sudo apt-get update works, sudo apt-get upgrade doesn't